# Examples of recursive descent parser

Tags: parsing, recursive-descent

What are some good examples of recursive descent parsers? Say from open source projects, or particularly good example code.

I'm especially looking to compare implementations with and without backtracking.

Examples in C, C++, Java, Javascript or Python preferred.

I'm aware there are parser generators which can generate various kinds of parsers. At the moment, I'm mainly interested in learning more about hand written recursive descent parsers.

Comment: http://oxyc.github.io/luaparse/

Comment: See my SO answer on how to implement recursive descent parsers:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/2336769/120163

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with this...but I know you can use JavaCC (without backtracking)
sample: https://java.net/projects/javacc/sources/svn/content/trunk/test/javaFiles/BaseSimpleNode.java?rev=635